# Python: while loop that quits program if not completed within specified limit

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, quit

Python Question:  i need to run a program that asks for a password but if the wrong answer is input three times the user is thrown out of the program i can run it in a while loop but cant get it to quit if the wrong password is entered.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Add the code that you have trouble with to your question.

Comment: Please, provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)/[MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help us help you!

Comment: Dumping smug, insider-joke acronyms on newcomers is oh so productive, even with reference.

Comment: ok guys youve lost me already - its bad enough im a 40 year old mom in a class of 19 year old boys trying to phatom python with out you throwing tla's at me - help im drowing....

Comment: Is your problem that you can't figure out how to bail out after 3 tries, or that you don't know how to exit the program?

Comment: @EWG we can help you best if you provide the code you're having trouble with.

Comment: Sorry Guys Im new to this forum ill enter it again with my program thats not working!!!  be prepared for it to be a rookie mistake!!!! im  like a cow looking into a field today!!!

Answer (score 4):

Adding an approximation of how I'd do it, in the absence of an example containing the problem.  `else` on a for loop will only execute if you did not break out of the loop.  Since you know the max number of times to run the loop is 3 you can just use a `for` loop instead of a `while` loop. `break` will still break you out early.

```
for _ in range(3):
    if raw_input("Password:") == valid_passwd:  # really should compare hashed values (as I shouldnt have passwords stored in the clear
        print "you guessed correctly"
        break
    print "you guessed poorly"
else:
    print "you have failed too many times, goodbye"
    sys.exit(1)
# continue on your merry (they got the right password)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about `sys.exit()`

```
>>> import sys
>>> guess = False
>>> if guess:
...     pass
... else:
...     sys.exit()
```

http://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html